# how to add a list of Elements in Firebase - XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to c # and I would like to know how I can insert a list of items in firebase.

VIEW MODEL

```
public async Task InsertarEjemplos (MEjemplo parametros)
    {

        await Constantes.firebase
            .Child("BDD")
            .PostAsync(new MEjemplo()
            {
                ejemplos = parametros.ejemplos
            }) ;
```

MODEL

```
 public class MEjemplo
{
    public string idEjemplo { get; set; }
    public List<object> ejemplos { get; set; }
```

The idea is that each element is added as shown in the image.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not in English

Comment: This belongs on https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: you may get better results from ... https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This was translated to English by people other than the original poster. Unless we have confirmation from @ayuda123 that they can converse in English, there is no benefit to attempting to answer this question in English.

Answer (score 0):

If you wat to insert data into Firebase database, you can take a look the following code:

```
  private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://xxxxxxxxx");
       await firebase
          .Child("MEjemplos")
          .PostAsync(new MEjemplo() { idEjemplo = "3", ejemplos = new List<object>() { "1 MEjemplo", "2 MEjemplo", "3 MEjemplo" } });

      List<MEjemplo> mes=  (await firebase
          .Child("MEjemplos")
          .OnceAsync<MEjemplo>()).Select(item => new MEjemplo
          {
              idEjemplo = item.Object.idEjemplo,
              ejemplos = item.Object.ejemplos
          }).ToList();

        
    }
```

[image]